# Using Apache/MIT licenced libraries in a closed source project

Tags: mit, apache-2.0

I've searched the web for hours trying to figure out if I'm using the licence properly, hopefully some one can enlighten me furthermore.

I own a start-up company that creates business-development tools for business of any kind, in some of our tools we develop on android, in order to install on a device, lock it with a kiosk app and sell it as a unit.

My question: assuming the unit make use of 3rd party library protected by Apache\MIT licences, does I use those library in a legit way? more info: the source code is closed, and the app will never reach the app store.

Answer (score 1):

The principal *pre*scriptions (there are also a few *pro*scriptions) applied to object-code-only distributions by the [Apache](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:Apache-2.0) and [3BSD](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:Apache-2.0) licences are, respectively,

> You must give any other recipients of the Work or
>             Derivative Works a copy of this License; and
>
> If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its
>             distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must
>             include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained
>             within such NOTICE file

and

> Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
>       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

As long as you honour those, you should be fine.  It's also generally considered a good idea to include the copyright statements from the Apache-licenced code.

Often tablet- or phone-app code includes this in a submenu, a behaviour you can see in almost any piece of free Android software.  Assuming you've got an Android phone, point it at https://f-droid.org and install a couple of free apps to see how it's done.  [This answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/9596/458) contains a short list of some such apps, and the locations of the license acknowledgments therein.