# Disclaimer of included open sourced libraries in project

Tags: commercial

This is my first post so I apologize in advanced if this question has been asked/answered before.

I have a question regarding the usage of open source libraries. We own several apps that are not open source, but use open source libraries that doesn't require our source code to be open sourced like LGPL, MIT, Apache, etc.

We've been through a long process of sanitizing our apps and remove libraries that require our code to be open sourced. Sadly, we can't go open source at the moment, but we are sure that the libraries that we use does not make as in infringement with any license, What we don't know is if we have to specify for each of the open source libraries that we use what license they have.

Do we have to include in our apps a screen that lists all the open source libraries that we use?. Do we have to include a file with this information?. Do we have to do anything at all?.

Comment: What you must include for any given library is a function of the licence on that library.  You should start by reading [Does a program need to show the open source license (Apache 2.0) of its components](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/9595/458), and if that doesn't answer your question, modify your question to clarify what you're still unsure of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a program need to show the open source license (Apache 2.0) of its components?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9595/does-a-program-need-to-show-the-open-source-license-apache-2-0-of-its-componen)

Comment: Thanks for the response!. @MadHatter I don't think i understood correctly what you mean by "function of the license on that library". Do I have to specify what I do with a library with a specific license?.

Comment: By reading the linked post if I understood correctly I should include in an about page or similar all the libraries licensed with apache 2.0 lic. Our apps are not open source, and use libraries with other licenses. Some of them specify clearly that some attribution should be included, others don't. The general advice is that you should do it with all of them but is a little impractical. What is your opinion?. Thanks again!

Comment: By "*What you must include for any given library is a function of the licence on that library*" I meant that your obligations in respect of any given library depend on its licence.  If `libfoo` is under 3BSD, you have certain obligations; if Apache2, slightly more; if GPLv3, considerably more, and so on: but in all cases the licence will tell you what your obligations are.  Then you need to look at the licence on `libbar`, and see what those obligations are.  Then the licence on `libbaz`, and so on.

Comment: Have you read the question I linked to yet?  I only ask because your question is picking up votes to close it as a duplicate thereof, and if you don't pretty soon read that question and refine your question in the light of it, this question is likely to get closed.

Comment: Hi @MadHatter. Yes I have. My conclusion after reading your responses and reading the related post is that it all depends on the licenses of the libraries that we are using. It is not neccesary then to include credits in an about page or similar if it is not explicitly required by the license, but it will be safer if we list all of them with it respective license in a file or dialog that give those libraries credit. Please confirm me if I understood correctly and I will mark your answer as the correct one. Thank you very much for your help and time!

Comment: I think you've grasped it, though if I write this up it'll say what I said, not your paraphrase.  If you think your summary is your preferred answer, you should write it up; the system will (at some later time) let you accept it, which you should also do.  Which would you prefer?