# Licensing an electron app made with third-party packages

Tags: licensing, mit, license-compatibility, license-recommendation, license-notice

I have an app made with [electron.js](https://www.electronjs.org/)

- I have used third party packages in my app.
- All the packages have permissive licenses(MIT and BSD License) with them.
- I am using UI assets(e.g. icons) with MIT license.

I want to license my app with MIT license

Now my questions are:

1. How do I license my app. Is it just as simple as adding MIT license copy in my repo.
2. Do I need to do something for third party packages licenses (for both packages dev and dep).
3. Some assets owner/authors did mention that I need to credit them in project. So how do I handle this, do I need to make a file with all their license and credits.

Comment: For question three, see eg [Does a program need to show the open source license (Apache 2.0) of its components?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/9595/458)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I have done it-

1. Yes it is as simple as that, beside that you can [License your app from GitHub repository it self](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/licensing-a-repository)
2. You can add a file(ThirdPartyLicense.txt) consisting all the licenses of dependencies and transitive dependencies in you main repository folder.
   This method is used by all big projects [example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode)
3. Add credit for third party in your app credits page.

Answer (score 0):

Third party packages are normally not uploaded to the repo and will be downloaded when someone tries to compile your electron app (by running `npm install`). If no third party code is included in your repo, I think it will be ok for just adding a license file to it.